# How to remove &amp; character during string save

Tags: c#

I have to set connection string in Web.config from my mvc controller. I already have written code like bellow and it can successfully edit the connection string in Web.config but the issue is that it adds extra characters when it saves in Web.config. Extra Characters are `&amp;` which i haven't provided in `string foo` variable. Then my question is why this getting added automatically during save in Web.config? How can i skip this characters from saving? Any idea?

From MVC controller i have set the connection string in `foo` variable like bellow:

```
string foo = @"metadata=res://*/edmxFileFactory.csdl|res://*/edmxFileFactory.ssdl|res://*/edmxFileFactory.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=10.110.1.77\MASK,59931;Initial Catalog=FileFactory;User ID=connectWeb;Password=conn123$;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;";
                var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
                var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
                section.ConnectionStrings["FileFactoryEntities"].ConnectionString = foo;
                configuration.Save();
```

In Web.config it saves like this bellow-

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FileFactoryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/edmxFileFactory.csdl|res://*/edmxFileFactory.ssdl|res://*/edmxFileFactory.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&amp;quot;Data Source=10.110.1.77\MASK,59931;Initial Catalog=FileFactory;User ID=connectWeb;Password=conn123$;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&amp;quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Where does `foo` come from? Can you replace `&quot;` in it with `"`? That will result in `&quot;` being written to your `web.config`.

Comment: Original one is just written in c# inside controller. As you can see i have stored in variable `foo`

Comment: `&amp;` is actually the `&` of `&quot;` that is being parsed.

Comment: You can see i am not passing `&amp;` at all. See carefully in `foo` variable

Comment: I'd change it then, `foo` contains escaped XML (`&quot;` instead of `"`). This is literally what you want to write to your file, but the mechanism by which that is written is doing the escaping for you. So it gets escaped twice. Hence `&amp;quot;`, as the `&` is being escaped.

Comment: Tell me solution for insert exactly same string which i set in `foo` variable

Comment: Replace `&quot;` with `"`.

Comment: You cant just remove this `&quot` bcoz its needed in connection string. Tell me how can i insert same string in Web.config if possible

Comment: I'm not suggesting you remove it, I'm suggesting you un-escape it - replace it with the double quote it represents. When it is written to `web.config` it will be correctly escaped if required.

Comment: Once it saved in Web.config i cant replace it anymore. Because it already saved then. This happens during save only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments tell you the solution; however, it seems, you misunderstand the point.

**TL;DR: The solution in one line:**

Replace every `&quot;` occurrence to `""` in the C# verbatim string `foo`.

**Explanation:**

In an XML attribute the quotation marks must be escaped, otherwise they could be confused by the quotes of the attribute itself. Hence when you save an attribute in XML containing quotes they will be escaped by the `&quot;` entity.

Now you copy-pasted the saved XML attribute without unescaping the entities (ie. you changed the value of `connection string="..."` to `connection string=&quot;...&quot;`). When such a value is about to be saved again, the XML writer will not see any quotes to escape but now sees ampersands, which must be escaped as well because normally in XML ampersand is the first character of an escaped entity. Therefore `&` is now replaced by `&amp;`.

In C# strings quote characters must be escaped as well. For regular strings you should use `\"` for a quote and in verbatim strings you must double the quotation marks. So just replace every `&quot;` to `""` in your `foo` C# variable and you are fine.

Comment: Works! Thanks dude. Just replaced `&quot;` to `""`